# jquery files conflict in mvc4 application

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an mvc4 application and implemented autocomplete in combobox refering http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox .The application works fine.But when i put the same code to another application,autocomplete combobox is not working.it is showing error 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method'..There is some conflict between the files..

How can i solve this??

Comment: did you make sure the order you called jquery.ui it should be after jquery

Answer (score 0):

make sure the jquery library isn't being added twice on the same page

Comment: no i have added only time time..But in scripts folder am having higher version files.Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that jQuery UI is included in `BundleConfig.cs` and then be sure that you are properly calling it on either your Layout.cshtml or your view page:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")    
}
```

Obviously, you need to call this dependency before you try to use it in code.

Good luck!

Comment: Well can you post the code you are using?  It is tough to spot your problem if you don't show us what your are doing.